# Platform.getBundle() is not working in eclipse mars

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

During migration of a RCP application from Eclipse Indigo (3.x) to Eclipse Mars (4.5.2), I am facing an issue.

**Platform.getBundle() is returning null.**

I found out that there is a file bundles.info which got created in " D:/Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/test.product/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator" folder.

There are 10 plugins in my project.

The information of all the plugins and required jars are present in **bundles.info** file. But one plugin(com.testPlugin) is missing in bundles.info file due to which Platform.getBundle() is returning null.

The information is in this way:
com.firstPlugin,6.1.1.qualifier,file:/D:/data/com.firstPlugin,4,false

The piece of code is written like this:

```
/**
 * Returns the actual absolute path of a given fragment depending on the
 * launching mode of Product.
 * 
 * @param fragmentID
 *            The symbolic name of a fragment, e.g.
 *            "com.test.design".
 * @return An {@code IPath} that contains the absolute path of given
 *         fragmentID regarding launching mode, or {@code null} if fragment
 *         is not found.
 */

public static IPath getFragmentPath(String fragmentID) {
    IPath fragmentPath = fragments.get(fragmentID);

    if (fragmentPath == null || fragmentPath.isEmpty()) {

        Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle(fragmentID);
        if (bundle == null) {
            fragmentPath = new Path(Constants.getAppPath()).append(
                    "plugins/").append(fragmentID);
        } else {
            try {
                fragmentPath = new Path(FileLocator.toFileURL(
                        bundle.getEntry("/")).getPath());
            } catch (IOException err) {
                ExceptionReporter.defaultReport(err);
                return null;
            }
        }
        fragments.put(fragmentID, fragmentPath);
    }

    return fragmentPath;
}
```

The **fragmentID** for that plugin is same as its name ie. com.testPlugin but since it is missing in bundles.info file, Platform.getBundle(fragmentID) is returning null and due to which I am not able to get the correct path.

My only concern is that why this plugin/bundle is missing in bundles.info.

The same code is working in eclipse indigo, but not in eclipse Mars(4.5.2)

Is there any API changes happened from Eclipse Indigo to Eclipse Mars.
Or what alternative can I use? I don't have BundleContext, so without using that what can we do in such case?

Comment: I don't know of any changes to this and it definitely still works as it is used all over the place. What bundle are you trying to find? There are many changes to plugins in Eclipse Mars, the one you want may have changed.

Comment: After debugging, I found out that it goes to ConfigApplier.class (from **org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator** ) and only one bundle is missing in the ArrayList of BundleInfo.

So, for that bundle only I am getting null , which is very much required in my application.

How can I figure out, why that bundle is missing and rest others are coming?

Comment: What bundle is missing?

Comment: It's related to the project which contains all the exe files.
For ex: zip.exe etc.

It contains plugin.xml and build.properties.

Build.properties contains

bin.includes = plugin.xml,\
               etc/,\
               bin/


So, If this bundle is missing, The **problem** is the path is not able to find zip.exe.

Comment: I checked there is file bundle.info which got created in the very beginning and that bundle is missing there. So, It is not able to find that bundle and Platform.getBundle() returns null in that case.

Do I have to make any change in eclipse 4.5.2, so that It can recognise this bundle?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. What is the bundle id that cannot be found? Edit your question and add more details.

Comment: Question edited! Please check as I have fix it asap. Not able to find any solution. what could be the problem?

Comment: It isn't usual to have a file URL in the bundle.info like that. I think you need to look at how you are building the RCP

Comment: I am not getting exactly, what could be the issue. 
But now I tried to export the product and I am getting this error:

Processing inclusion from feature com.testPlugin: Unable to find plug-in: com.testPlugin. Please check the error log for more details.


In the error log: same message is written; Plugin is org.eclipse.pde.build

Comment: So this is nothing to do with `Platform.getBundle` which is working correctly. You need to go through your product definition and how you are exporting to see what the issue is.